# Hosting a JEE application on my own server with custom domain

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, hosting, web-hosting

I have a website which purpose is to help people build routes and use various map tools. The site is all static with lots of javascript source files which do the logic.

However i want to convert this site to a JEE application and host it on my own server with tomcat container.

So lets say that the application hosted on my server can be accessed on address: ***xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084/MyApp***

Now lets say my domain is ***www.my-domain.com***

The question is:

Is it possible to be made when i enter ***www.my-domain.com*** in the browser to load automatically ***xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084/MyApp***

Comment: Although it's not the only issue with this question, I have to stress explicitly that Apache Tomcat is a Java Web and not a Java EE server because that's a common issue.

Answer (score 1):

DNS translates host names to IP addresses *only*. It cannot forward ports or URLs.

The simplest solution would be to run the application on your server on port 80 and run in the `ROOT` context.

Make the home page one of the defaults or override it as defined in the [Tomcat FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_override_the_default_home_page_loaded_by_Tomcat.3F)s.

Your domain provider generally provides basic DNS services and you should be able to tell them to point that URL at your IP.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is not possible without doing some extra work.

You can achieve this in two ways

1. Configuring Tomcat's [HTTP connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) in server.xml to listen on port 80 and configure your app to run in the `ROOT` context.
2. Add an Apache HTTPD (or NGINX if that suits your taste) reverse proxy which listens on port 80 and connects locally to your Tomcat service

I would **NOT** recommend option 1.
For option 2, the tomcat website has a [howto available](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html).